# operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer in PostgreSql

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

I came across with a strange issue in postgres. I have two databases create in two different periods.
Both are running in the same PostrgreSql 9.6 version in the same machine. When I run the query `SELECT now() + 30` in database 1 -> Its working properly.
The same query I am copy paste in the second database, its giving error:  `operator does not exist: timestamp with time zone + integer` in PostgreSql

Can some one guide me on this.

[image]

Comment: that's messed up,  how many `now()` functions does database1 have and what are their return-types?  what casts are defined on `timestamptz`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added the below query to solve the issue.

CREATE OPERATOR + ( PROCEDURE = adddays,LEFTARG = TIMESTAMPTZ, RIGHTARG = NUMERIC,COMMUTATOR = +); CREATE OPERATOR - ( PROCEDURE = adddays,LEFTARG = TIMESTAMPTZ, RIGHTARG = NUMERIC,COMMUTATOR = -);

Note: When ever I had restored the database, I used to get this issue.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe someone created the operator with those types in one database, but not in the other one.

```
create function addit(timestamptz,int) returns timestamptz immutable language sql as $$ 
    select $1+ interval '1 day'*$2 
$$;
create operator + (leftarg =timestamptz, rightarg =int, procedure=addit);
```

Comment: Thanks @jjanes. But while running the above code in the database, I am getting the below error: "  WARNING:  operator attribute "function" not recognized
ERROR:  operator procedure must be specified
********** Error ********** "

Comment: Sorry, in 9.6 it must be spelled 'procedure'.  'function' wasn't added as a synonym for that until 11.

Comment: the query executed very well, Thanks. 
Can we get the return format as date(yyyy-MM-dd). Now it is returning the result as timestamp with time zone.

Comment: change the select to `select $1::date + $2`, this changes the rreturn type so you'll need to drop the operatot and the function and redefine both.